# Spark: How to configure writetime while saving to cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, timestamp, spark-cassandra-connector

I have an entity which resembles to a cassandra table. I am using spark to save/update the data into Cassandra. Here the entity is **Offer** case class

```
case class Offer(offer_id: String, metadata_last_modified_source_time: Timestamp, product_type: String, writeTime: util.Date)

val offerDataset: Dataset[Offer] = ....
```

I am saving this data as below

```
offerDataset.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map("keyspace" -> cassandraKeyspace, "table" -> tableName))
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .save()
```

The cassandra table's schema is

```
OFFER(offer_id, metadata_last_modified_source_time, product_type)
```

**The problem is to configure *writeTime* field of *Offer* entity as write timestamp while saving/updating the cassandra table. It is mentioned here in datastax - https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md to configure like**

```
writetime=columnName
```

[image]

What I couldn't understand is how should the syntax look like.

Any help could be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This documentation is for alpha version of the Spark Cassandra Connector, so please expect something not working.  As pointed in documentation - this is a table option, so you can set it via `options`.  You only need to switch from `util.Date` to `Timestamp` or `Long` types - Spark SQL doesn't support encoding from `Date` type.

with following definitions everything works:

```scala
import java.time.Instant
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Offer(offer_id: String, metadata_last_modified_source_time: Timestamp, 
  product_type: String, writeTime: Long)

val offerDataset = Seq(Offer("123", Timestamp.from(Instant.now()), "test", 1243124234L),
  Offer("456", Timestamp.from(Instant.now()), "test", 12431242366L)).toDF
```

or with `Timestamp`:

```scala
case class Offer(offer_id: String, metadata_last_modified_source_time: Timestamp, 
   product_type: String, writeTime: Timestamp)

val offerDataset = Seq(Offer("123", Timestamp.from(Instant.now()), "test", new Timestamp(1243124234L)),
  Offer("456", Timestamp.from(Instant.now()), "test", new Timestamp(12431242366L))).toDF
```

if we use following table structure:

```
create table test.wrt_test (
  offer_id text,
  metadata_last_modified_source_time timestamp,
  product_type text,
  primary key(offer_id, metadata_last_modified_source_time));
```

then you can save data as following (**only in 3.0-alpha!**):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
offerDataset.write.cassandraFormat("wrt_test", "test")
    .option("writetime", "writeTime") // here you specify name of the column with time!
    .mode(SaveMode.Append).save()
```

but it also works just fine in the current release version, if you use RDD API:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.writer._
offerDataset.rdd.saveToCassandra("test", "wrt_test", 
   writeConf = WriteConf(timestamp = TimestampOption.perRow("writeTime")))
```

After writing in both cases you get following:

```
cqlsh> select offer_id, metadata_last_modified_source_time, product_type, writetime(product_type) from test.wrt_test;
offer_id | metadata_last_modified_source_time | product_type | writetime(product_type)
----------+------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------
      123 |    2020-04-16 07:28:38.905000+0000 |         test |              1243124234
      456 |    2020-04-16 07:28:38.905000+0000 |         test |             12431242366
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt. This 'option("writetime", "writeTime")' failed  whereas this one worked 'offerDataset.rdd.saveToCassandra("test", "wrt_test", 
   writeConf = WriteConf(timestamp = TimestampOption.perRow("writeTime")))'

Comment: what SCC version have you used? As I wrote - it's available only in the alpha version of SCC

Comment: am using 2.0.3 which I can't change due to my project constraints

Comment: then only using RDD you can reach it

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade for at least 2.0.latest - there were a lot of fixes and performance optimizations